# Seg fault on last line of code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm hoping to implement a simple molecular dynamics program. My first step is to define the system as a series of atoms, each with a type, an id number, a 3 dimensional position vector, and a 3D velocity vector. Below is the program I've written to do so:

```
FILE *init;

static int randomVelocity(void)  
{  
     return rand()/RAND_MAX - 0.5;  
}  


int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{  

    int iType;  
    int iID;  
    int i;  
    double* pdPosition;  
    double* pdVelocity;  
    char* line;  
    Atom* poAtoms;  
    int count = 0;  

    init = fopen("newdat.txt", "r+");  
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));  
    line = malloc(81*sizeof(char));  
    while (fgets(line, 80, init) != NULL)    
    {  
         char* tok1;  
         char* tok2;  
         char* tok3;  
         char* tok4;  
         tok1 = strtok(line, " \t");  
         if ((tok1 == NULL) || (tok1[0] == '*'))   
         {  
              break;  
         }  
         tok2 = strtok(NULL, " \t");  
         tok3 = strtok(NULL, " \t");  
         tok4 = strtok(NULL, " \t");  
         iType = atoi(tok1);  
         iID = count;  
         pdPosition = (double*)malloc(3*sizeof(double));  
         pdVelocity = (double*)malloc(3*sizeof(double));     
         pdPosition[0] = atof(tok2);  
         pdPosition[1] = atof(tok3);  
         pdPosition[2] = atof(tok4);  
         pdVelocity[0] = randomVelocity();  
         pdVelocity[1] = randomVelocity();    
         pdVelocity[2] = randomVelocity();  
         poAtoms[count] = Atom_new(iType, iID, pdPosition, pdVelocity);  
         count++;  
    }  

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)  
    {  
         Atom_print(poAtoms[i]);  
         Atom_free(poAtoms[i]);  
    }   

    free(line);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Here is the header file atom.h:

```
/**** atom.h ****/


typedef struct Atom_str *Atom;  

Atom Atom_new(int iType, int iID, double* adPosition, double* adVelocity);  

void Atom_free(Atom oAtom);  

void Atom_print(Atom oAtom);
```

and the test input file:

```
1 5 7 9  
2 12 13 14
```

The program compiles, but when I run it, I get the expected output followed by a seg fault. I'm using the GDB debugger, and the seg fault appears to happen on the very last line of code, after the return statement! Is it a memory management issue?

Comment: These types of problems are often related to memory corruption. Can you type "bt" after the crash in GDB and see if there's a stack trace, and post it if so? Or use Valgrind.

Comment: Is this the stack trace you were referring to? #0  0x0804b3fd in ?? ()
#1  0x00000001 in ?? ()  
#2  0xffffd8b4 in ?? ()  
#3  0xffffd8bc in ?? ()  
#4  0x00722828 in ?? ()  
#5  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've never `malloc`ed memory for `poAtoms`. Writing to wherever that uninitialized pointer points can easily cause a segfault.

Before you start reading the file, you should allocate some space,

```
unsigned expected_count = 2; // for the test input file, would be much larger in real runs
poAtoms = malloc(expected_count*sizeof(*poAtoms));
```

And then you have to check inside the read-loop that you're not writing past the allocated memory. Before

```
    poAtoms[count] = Atom_new(iType, iID, pdPosition, pdVelocity);
```

insert a check,

```
    if (expected_count <= count)
    {
        expected_count *= 2;   // double the space, could also be a smaller growth factor
        Atom *temp = realloc(poAtoms, expected_count*sizeof(*poAtoms));
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            perror("Reallocation failed, exiting\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        poAtoms = temp;
    }
```

if the allocated space for `poAtoms` is already used, try to get more with `realloc`, if that fails, abort unless you know how to fix it. If the reallocation succeeds, we can continue collecting new atoms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Daniel! I am providing the code for my atom.c file: struct Atom_str
{  
     int iType;  
     int iID;  
     double* pdPosition;  
     double* pdVelocity;  
};  

Atom Atom_new(int iType, int iID, double* adPosition, double* adVelocity)  
{  
     Atom oAtom;  
     oAtom = (Atom)malloc(sizeof(struct Atom_str));    
     if (oAtom == NULL)  
          return NULL;   
     oAtom->iType = iType;  
     oAtom->iID = iID;  
     oAtom->pdPosition = adPosition;  
     oAtom->pdVelocity = adVelocity;  
     return oAtom;
}

Comment: Sorry for the strange formatting there... but what I meant to say was that I did malloc space for the atom struct using the line "oAtom = (Atom)malloc(sizeof(struct Atom_str));" Am I not malloc-ing enough memory, perhaps?

Comment: Well, that's irrelevant here, because between the declaration `Atom* poAtoms;` and the write `poAtoms[count] = Atom_new(iType, iID, pdPosition, pdVelocity);`, there is no mention whatsoever of `poAtoms`. So `poAtoms` points to whatever the bits that accidentally occupied its position on the stack indicate, and that's where the return value of `Atom_new` is written. In your case, that seems to have overwritten part of the program exit code.

Comment: @user1125353 you're `malloc`ing for the `struct Atom_str`, the payload, but not for the `Atom` pointers to the payload.

Comment: Okay, I think I see... Are you saying that poAtoms is actually an array of pointers? In which case, should I declare it as "Atom** poAtoms;"? And then should I include a line like "poAtoms[count] = (Atom*)malloc(sizeof(int));"? (Because a pointer is just an int address, correct?)

Comment: Since an `Atom` is a pointer to `Atom_str`, `poAtoms` is indeed an array of pointers to `Atom_str` (by intent, not exactly since arrays aren't pointers). The declaration of `poAtoms` is correct, as `Atom*` it is an `Atom_str**`. I'll put a correct malloc line in the answer for readability. Note: a pointer is not an int address, for one, it's unsigned (doesn't matter for the size), more importantly it's often the size of a `long`, on 64-bit systems a pointer is 8 bytes, while int is typically 4.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense; thank you so much! I'm sorry though - where did you put the correct malloc line? (I'm new to this forum and don't know my way around just yet...)

Answer (score 0):

What is tok1[0] doing in if condition ? Did you check a small code snippet for strtok that what is returned or  checked when you try to print tok1[[0]?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what does 1 5 7 9 represent in input file ? are thei type id and velocity .
If so you can manipulate and differentiate them by hyphen and extract each value by strtok as NULL. Also check if fgets is appending NULL or may be * as you have tried to check in if  condition probably for End of line . I have a gut felling that it can be the place where you are going wrong , Or if you can pleas explain your input file it would be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 1 is the atom type; the 5, 7, and 9 should be the x, y, and z components of the position vector, respectively. (The three components of the velocity vector are provided by a random number generator.) The if (tok1[0] == '*') part of my code is supposed to let my input file have comments, delimited by '*'... but I probably need to think that through a bit more! :)